# how to remove quarantine from file permissions in os x

Tags: permissions, files, osx, xattr

I downloaded a .pem file and my Mac OS X (10.8.2) added an `@` sign at the end of the file permissions. This is causing file permission issues. I can't seem to remove the quarantine flag. I even tried the command

```
xattr -d <filename>.pem
```

but that didn't work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

xattr -d requires you to specify which attribute you want to remove.  You can find this out by listing the file attributes by passing ls the -@ flag as in:

```
ls -l@ filename
```

Once you know what the attribute is, you can target it for removal with -d or you can use the following to clear all attributes:

```
xattr -c filename
```